# VB.net Loop adding to combobox

Tags: vb.net, loops, combobox

Spent about an hour now, with multiple rages at my monitor. I have a variable which stores the amount of elements within an array.

I want to add the numbers '1' up to this variable number to a combobox. So that when i use the combobox, it gives the options of 1,2,3 etc up to the variable number. If anyone could help, that would a fantastic!!

Also, I tried a few different loops but caused visual studio to give an unable to access debug error when i tried to run the program. I am new to this so apologies if this seems basic.

The code I have below stores the count.

```
accno = custdetails.Count
```

Comment: why dont you show what you have tried so  we arent starting from zero

Comment: I would however I could never test if it actually worked or not as visual studio keeps returning the cannot access file debug error.

Comment: edit your post - code does not format in comments

Comment: I cannot find the code, basically i was using a do until the variable = accno. I then was adding 1 to another variable and used combobox.items.add to add these numbers. But this was causing the problem, i have since restarted the program twice and therefore cannot find the code, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write the loop. This is a one-liner:

```
MyCombobox.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, accno).ToArray())
```

I prefer that because it starts you thinking in terms of matching your presentation to a data source, which will help you a lot as you learn further.

But if you really want to:

```
For i As Integer = 1 to accno
    MyCombobox.Items.Add(i)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Used the for loop as it the first statement caused a cannot convert to 1 dimensional object from 1 dimensional integer. Thanks anyway!!